# Setting a title in a tabbed view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

In my storyboard my application starts with a navigation controller, then it connects to a tabbed view controller, which then branches off onto three separate tabs. The problem is I can figure out how to set a title for the individual tabs? They all just take the title of the tabbed view controller when the application is launched. I have no code written for the storyboard yet, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a navigation controller as the root controller rather than the tab bar controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work for you

[self setTitle:@"Test View"];

Answer (score 0):

The scenes that lead from the tab bar should have a `Tab Bar Item`:

[image]

In the 'Attributes Inspector' are fields, where you can define the image and title for the tab bar item:
[image]

What you enter here, will be shown in the tab bar.